# Nautilus icons are missing on KDE

Tags: nautilus, icons, kde, kde4

I really like Nautilus file manager, but on KDE the icons are missing. It works good on Unity and Gnome.

If I start nautilus from Terminal (writting `nautilus`) I see the following logs:

```
$ nautilus
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.4.0

(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/22 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/24 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/32 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/48 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/64 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/128 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/192 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory   of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(nautilus:29369): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/22 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/24 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/32 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/48 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/64 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/128 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  apps/192 of theme unity-webapps has no size field
(nautilus:29369): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory   of theme unity-webapps has no size field
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

And a screen shot:

> [image]

How can I fix them?

I also see "X" icons in other applications running under KDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For having your GTK3 applications show icons correctly you need a set of packages installed:

```
sudo apt-get install kdeartwork-theme-icon gtk3-engines-oxygen kde-config-gtk-style
```

You also need to configure GTK applications to use oxygen, look for KDE System Settings -> Appearance panel, make sure that using KDE themes in GTK apps is activated. This should give you the kde-look into your GTK applications.

Sources:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_Qt_and_GTK_Applications
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/kde-gtk-config-tool-gives-greater-control-over-gtk-theming-in-kde
- https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/base/kde-gtk-config

Answer (score 1):

2016-02 I also had my icons disappear.

Fixed it by going to "System Settings -> Appearance" and selecting a theme, the setting was blank.